# How to pack arguments of a function into a vector for brevity?

Tags: formatting, vector, products

I have a function like the following one:

```
F[a_, b_, c_, d_] := Product[f[x, y, z, j, i], {j, a, b}, {i, c, d}]
```

where

```
f[x,y,z,j,i]
```

is some other simple function. I am interested for the double product of $f(x,y,z,j,i)$ for the specific values of $a,b,c,d$. My question is how can I pack those into a 4-vector or 2 2-vectors so when I call the function $F$ to call something like

```
F[{a,b,c,d}]
```

I need to understand how to do this in order to generalize when I have different sets of $\{a,b,c,d \}$.

In other words how can I call $F[K]$ where $K$ is a vector with 4 entries?

An example would be 
$$
\prod_{j=a}^b \prod_{i=c}^d (x+iy+jz)
$$

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: `F[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := Product[f[x, y, z, j, i], {j, a, b}, {i, c, d}]`?

Comment: Yes, that it is take the product of $f$ with j running from $a$ to $b$ and with $i$ running from $c$ to $d$. That is $\prod_{j=a}^{b} \prod_{i=c}^{d} f(x,y,z,j,i)$

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I think you may have overlooked the curly braces in Dr. belisarius's left-hand side. He was proposing a solution. :)

Comment: What about `F[v_List] := 
 Product[f[x, y, z, j, i], {j, v[[1]], v[[2]]}, {i, v[[-2]], v[[-1]]}]` ?

Comment: Let me try it out :)

Comment: Does not seem to work, I put F[2,2,2,2] and I get back F[2,2,2,2]. Also why in the $i$ multiplication you use v[[-2]] and v[[-1]]? All four should be independent. (Also how do I put code in comments?)

Comment: You should input `F[{a,b,c,d}]`, not `F[a,b,c,d]`. Also try the first comment first.

Comment: Ah, ok, right I see. Ok thanks a lot :) But I would like to also know how to add predetermined sets. I.e. F[A] where A={a,b,c,d} since I want to do so for many different A's

Comment: If `v={a,b,c,d}` what do you think will happen when you evaluate `F[v]`? Just try.

Comment: As well as modifying the definition of your function you can also do `f @@ v` (if and only if `v` is a list).

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks for the help, I am just getting into mathematica